# Thrift - Scala to Php( unable to retrieve data from database dynamically)

Tags: php, scala, neo4j, thrift, thrift-protocol

I developed a Scala project with Neo4j embedded as database. I used Thrift service to call the Scala functions from Php files. Am am able to insert data into the Neo4j database by calling Scala functions from Php files using Thrift. But the problem is, whenever I try to get the data from Neo4j database am not able to get the newly inserted data. Am getting the complete data only when I restart the Thrift service. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you creating an in-memory database?